# Base in topological space

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces, change-of-basis, product-space

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be the basis in the topological space $(X,\tau)$. Will $B_1\cup B_2$ and $B_1\cap B_2$ be the base?

I think intuitively it would be $B_1\cup B_2$. But $B_1\cap B_2$ may not be either. Would you help me with this topic?

I know the base definition. However, since I did not understand the subject well in the course, I have difficulties in the proofs or examples here.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different collections of sets may be bases for a given topology.

Notice that $B_{0} \cup B_{1} \subseteq \tau$.
This means every element of $B_{i}$ is the union of finite intersections of elements in $B_{1 - i}$. You can't get any new open sets that were not in $\tau$.

To see that $B_{0} \cap B_{1}$ need not be a basis for $\tau$. Consider two basis for the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. The elements of $B_{0}$ are open disks.
The elements of $B_{1}$ are open squares. Since no disk is a square and no square is a disk, the intersection is empty. The topology generated by $\varnothing$ is $\{ \varnothing, \mathbb{R}^{2}\}$, not the usual topology.

Comment: Neither intersection nor union is a base, then? @Jay

Comment: The union of two bases for a given topology is a basis for that topology. The intersection of two bases for a topology need not be a basis for that topology.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jay